get speed from gpxpy.GpxTrack
i trying to get speed,course from gpx track
my trackPoint
<trkpt lon="77.209995" lat="28.520444"><ele>236.502853</ele><time>2022-02-20T02:04:51Z</time><extensions><speed>0.788036</speed><course>209.456757</course><hAcc>6.222376</hAcc><vAcc>1.408607</vAcc></extensions></trkpt>

with open('kaggle/input/workout-routes/route_2022-02-02_8.06pm.gpx', 'r') as gpx_file:
    gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)
route_info = []

for track in gpx.tracks:
    for segment in track.segments:
        for ind, point in enumerate(segment.points):
            print(point.speed)
            route_info.append({
                'latitude': point.latitude,
                'longitude': point.longitude,
                'elevation': point.elevation,
                'time': np.datetime64(point.time),
                'course': point.course
            })

point.speed = None
i trying to get speed with extensions like this
point.extensions

and get [<Element 'speed' at 0x000001ADBB50A7A0>]
how i can get speed and at it in route_info

To get the speed from the extensions in a GPX track point using gpxpy, you can extract the extension data manually.
First, parse the code using::::
with open('your_gpx_file.gpx', 'r') as gpx_file:
    gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)  

then repeat through tracks and segments with:
for track in gpx.tracks:
    for segment in track.segments:
        for point in segment.points:
            # Process each point

then extract speed from extension:
speed = None
course = None
for extension in point.extensions:
    if extension.tag == 'speed':
        speed = float(extension.text)
    if extension.tag == 'course':
        course = float(extension.text)

then store the data in list:
route_info.append({
    'latitude': point.latitude,
    'longitude': point.longitude,
    'elevation': point.elevation,
    'time': np.datetime64(point.time),
    'speed': speed,
    'course': course
})

It will give you the list of dictionaries with latitude, longitude, elevation, time, speed, and course for each track point in the GPX file.
